# Waiting on Meteor.user()

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

If a new users signs up, I take them to the getting started route so they enter can enter a name which is at `/gs`. I store the name inside a name property of the profile object of the current user. Now if a user who has already entered a name and visits the `/gs` route I want to redirect them to the root. In iron router, I do this:

```
Router.route('/gs', {
  name: 'gs',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    if ( Meteor.user().profile.name ) {
      this.redirect('/');
    } else {
      this.render();
    }
  }
});
```

Even though this works, it prints out 2 errors to the console. One of them being "Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined" and the lack of `this.next()`. Any way to fix these problems.

Comment: Try this: `if ( Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.name ) {`

Answer (score 5):

> Your route functions and most hooks are run in a reactive computation. This means they will rerun automatically if a reactive data source changes. For example, if you call Meteor.user() inside of your route function, your route function will rerun each time the value of Meteor.user() changes. ([Iron.Router Guide: Reactivity](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/282e300e88cb3449e5c694f9847b28946edd8a59/Guide.md#reactivity))
>
> Hook functions and all functions that get run when dispatching to a route are run in a reactive computation: they will rerun if any reactive data sources invalidate the computation. In the above example, if Meteor.user() changes the entire set of route functions will be run again.
> ([Iron.Router Guide: Using Hooks](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/282e300e88cb3449e5c694f9847b28946edd8a59/Guide.md#using-hooks))

The first time the function is run, `Meteor.user()` is `undefined`. Then its value change to an object. As it is a reactive variable, the function is run again, without error this time.

You should check if `Meteor.user()` is defined before using its properties. Here is a very (maybe too much) exhaustive way of doing so:

```
if (Meteor.user() !== undefined) {
  // the user is ready
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    // the user is logged in
    if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.name) {
      // the name is already set
      this.redirect('/');
    } else {
      this.render();
  } else {
    // the user is not logged in
} else {
  // waiting for the user to be ready
}
```

Comment: YES! This works. I've been stuck on this for a very long time. Here's my function to help others:

Router.route('/account',{
 fastRender: true,
 data:function(){
  
  if( Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.guest ){
   Router.go('/login');
  } else {
   Router.go('/account');
  }
 },
 template:'screen',
 yieldTemplates: {
  'account': {to: 'content'},
 }
 
});

Answer (score 0):

Pandark has the correct answer, wanted to share my working code!

```
Router.route('/account',{
fastRender: true,
data:function(){

    if( Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile.guest ){
        Router.go('/login');
    } else {
        Router.go('/account');
    }
},
template:'screen',
yieldTemplates: {
    'account': {to: 'content'},
}
});
```